# How to get all attributes in .csv from the twitter data in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to fetch data of my twitter account and want to export it to the .csv file. I have got following code for the same. By using this code, I am getting only 3 attributes such as **ID, create_at and Text**. I want to fetch all attributes in .csv file. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import tweepy
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import time
import csv
#from tweepy import twitter_credentials
```

```
def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    #Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method
    
    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  
    
    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)
    
    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    
    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    
    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print(f"getting tweets before {oldest}")
        
        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)
        
        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
        
        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        
        print(f"...{len(alltweets)} tweets downloaded so far")
    
    #transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text] for tweet in alltweets]
    
    #write the csv  
    with open(f'new_{screen_name}_tweets.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)
    
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be because you are just trying to fetch those pieces of information from the result.

A reference to the resulting `Status` object is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-status-object-in-tweepy/)

```
def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    #Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method
    
    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  
    
    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)
    
    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    
    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    
    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print(f"getting tweets before {oldest}")
        
        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)
        
        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
        
        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        
        print(f"...{len(alltweets)} tweets downloaded so far")
    
    #transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
    outtweets = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweet.id_str, tweet.text, tweet.entities, tweet.source, tweet.source_url, tweet.in_reply_to_status_id, tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str, tweet.in_reply_to_user_id, tweet.in_reply_to_user_id_str, tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name, tweet.user.id,tweet.user.name, tweet.geo, tweet.coordinates, tweet.place, tweet.contributors, tweet.is_quote_status, tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count, tweet.favorited, tweet.retweeted, tweet.lang] for tweet in alltweets]
    
    #write the csv  
    with open(f'new_{screen_name}_tweets.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["created_at", "id", "id_str", "text", "entities", "source", "source_url", "in_reply_to_status_id", "in_reply_to_status_id_str", "in_reply_to_user_id", "in_reply_to_user_id_str", "in_reply_to_screen_name", "user_id","user_name", "geo", "coordinates", "place", "contributors", "is_quote_status", "retweet_count", "favorite_count", "favorited", "retweeted", "lang"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)
    
    pass
```

for the user, as it is an object, you can access its properties by appending a comma and the name of the property, such as: `tweet.user.id` or `tweet.user.name`.

The list of the property names can be found in the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/user-object).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. But it is giving following error. 

**name 'created_at' is not defined**

Comment: I updated the code, have forgotten the `tweet.` in the array, let me know if you managed to have it fixed

Comment: reuptaded, let me know if helped =)

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is giving following error at the end.

**AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'possibly_sensitive'**

So I tried after removing that attribute. So csv file is generated. In user column, it is giving **User(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x0000014364CBBDC0>, _json={'id': 623205342, 'id_str': '623205342'......** information

Comment: yes because user is an object, containing more information inside of it, you should check the documentation on what information there are in the User object and then store the data you want to achieve in the csv. the documentation is here: [tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html) and [user object in twitter docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/user-object)

Comment: reupdated the answer to have some of the user properties on it

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.
I am looking to extract following attributes. Can you please guide me?

**Tweet ID**,
**Username**,
**Tweet**,
**link**,
**Time**,
**Retweet**,
**Reply to User**,
**Retweeted By**,
**Number of Retweets**,
**Hashtags**,
**Mentions**,
**Name**,
**Number of Tweets**,
**Number of Followers**,
**Number Following**,
**Number of Likes**,
**No. of  Comments**,

I know its bit lengthy. I heartily thank you.

Comment: sorry but i already gave you all of the information you need to get all of those data (in the answer and docs), you just have to read the documentation in order to get what and where you want the information. the user is one object, so it has properties, each tweet is an object, so it has other properties as well

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can I ask for a small favor?

```outtweets = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweet.id_str, tweet.text, tweet.entities, tweet.source, ] for tweet in alltweets]```

In this code, how can I write when I want to extract from user object? Will it be ```tweet.user.[attributes from the documentation]```?

Comment: yes, exactly, and don't forget to add below as a name of the column of the csv you want as well, ex: if you add: `tweet.user.id`, don't forget below in the `writer.writerow` line to add `"user_id"` or something similar, that will be the header of your column